# I'm using Pytest to check my update function, I don't what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, pytest

I'm using Pytest to create a test for my functions. I do not know what is wrong with my test. I added my query from my programme.

This is for windows and I'm reading a Sqlite3 data. My current code is working, but my test for my update function is not responding.

```
def test_update_record_of_table(capsys):

    connection = sqlite3.connect("Northwind.db", timeout=10)

    cursor_db = connection.cursor()

    cursor_db.execute("select count(*) from test")
    before_count = cursor_db.fetchone()[0]

    cursor_db.execute("INSERT INTO {table_name}({fields}) VALUES ({new_record});".format(table_name='test', fields=tuple('CategoryName'), new_record=1400))

    print("before_count", before_count)
    assign_12_2.update_record_of_table("test", "CategoryName", "asdssf", 3, cursor_db)

    cursor_db.execute("select CategoryName from test")
    a = cursor_db.fetchall()[0]
    connection.commit()
    print(a)

    assert before_count
```

This is my error:

> cursor_db.execute("INSERT INTO {table_name}({fields}) VALUES ({new_record});".format(table_name='test', fields=tuple('CategoryName'), new_record=1400))
>
> E       sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
>
> OperationalError

Comment: Can you change to `cursor_db.execute('insert into test values (1400)')`? If that works, try `cursor_db.execute('insert into {table_name} values (1400)'.format(table_name='test'))`. Does that work?

Comment: No, none of them works. This is the error:OperationalError: table test has 3 columns but 1 values were supplied

Comment: Try this `cursor_db.execute('insert into test (categoryname) values (1400)')`. If that works, try `cursor_db.execute( 'insert into {} (categoryname) values (1400)'.format('test') )`. If that works, try `cursor_db.execute( 'insert into {} ({}) values (1400)'.format('test', 'categoryname') )`. If that works, try `cursor_db.execute( 'insert into {} ({}) values ({})'.format('test', 'categoryname', 1400) )`

Comment: No, none of them works. The error is ProgrammingError: an Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 6 supplied.

Comment: Is there any other approach for this test?

Comment: Go to sqlite command prompt and type `.schema test`. That'll dump the `create table ...` statement. Can you share that? Also, what version of SQLite are you using?

Comment: I'm using SQLit3 version 3/, Pycharm 3 & Pytest for my test

Comment: Here is the error: cursor_db.schema('test')
AttributeError: 'sqlite3.Cursor' object has no attribute 'schema'

Comment: I'm going to think about another way to do this test. Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Looks like you might have to change `fields=tuple('CategoryName')` to `fields='CategoryName'`. Try that out. I was able to write equivalent code in my environment and run that successfully. If you want that code, I can type out an answer.